# Metric independent gauge-fixing conditions for gauge theories

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

For instance, the Lorenz gauge conditions $$\partial^{\mu}A^a_{\mu} = 0$$ is implicitly dependent on the metric because of the raised index of the partial derivative. So, is there a metric independent gauge-fixing condition that one can implement for gauge theories?

Comment: Would you allow non-covariant gauges, e.g. temporal gauge $A^a_0=0$?

Comment: Are you just talking about Yang-Mills here?

Comment: @Qmechanic Even that gauge is metric dependent because you can write that gauge as $n^{\mu}A^a_{\mu} = 0$, where $n^{\mu} = \delta^{\mu}_0$. Any inner-product is implicitly metric dependent.

Comment: @NiharKarve Yes